# TP-Link TL-SG108PE - 802.1Q VLAN config

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I have a scenario where I need to connect 2 groups of devices using 5 switches to 2 different routers.
I'm thinking that 802.1Q VLAN would be the solution.

I would create two VLAN's, one for each device group and have the following connections between the switches/routers:

1. Switch 1 Port 8 connecting to Switch 5 Port 8 - Tagged - VLAN1,2
2. Switch 2 Port 8 connecting to Switch 1 Port 7 - Tagged - VLAN1,2
3. Switch 3 Port 8 connecting to Switch 1 Port 6 - Tagged - VLAN1,2
4. Switch 4 Port 8 connecting to Switch 1 Port 5 - Tagged - VLAN1,2
5. Switch 5 Port 8 connecting to Switch 1 Port 5 - Tagged - VLAN1,2
6. Switch 5 Port 6 connecting to Router 1 - Untagged - VLAN1
7. Switch 5 Port 7 connecting to Router 2 - Untagged - VLAN2

A picture of the setup:

[image: Switch port table]

Will this setup work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In theory,** it's a very typical 802.1Q setup and should work fine.

(If the switch has "PVID" settings, make sure your "tagged" ports have the same PVID. In some switches the 'trunk' or 'tagged' mode indeed means "tag everything", but in some other switches it means "tag everything *except* the PVID VLAN", which remains untagged.)

**However,** I've heard from a few different people that TL-SG108PE (and the whole series) has issues with its VLAN implementation. That is, no matter what tagging settings you use, *all ports* will be able to receive traffic assigned to VLAN 1. (That is especially an issue with broadcasts, such as ICMPv6 RAs, which can greatly confuse devices when they arrive on the 'wrong' VLAN.)

A possible workaround might be to reserve VLAN 1 as the "management" VLAN, and shift your "Internet" and "Siemens" networks to VIDs **2 and 3** respectively. (All port 8s would become "1 untagged, 2/3 tagged".) I haven't tried this practically.

For example, [this Netgate forum thread](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/107152/tp-link-tl-sg108e-vlan-1/5), or [this Amazon review](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CUG8ESM):

> Regardless of PVID or 802.1Q VLANs, every port on this switch passes untagged traffic on VLAN 1. Even if you set another VLAN to be untagged on a given port, you cannot then remove VLAN 1 from that port

Answer (score 1):

I have a TL-SG1016PE, and, as @user1686 said, it has some strange behavior regarding VLAN1 (it seems to be propagated untagged in some cases).

However, I was able to fix it by using the following configuration:

- Enable `802.1Q VLAN PVID`
- Set all ports to have PVID `2`. **WARNING** *this will probably break your connection. Remember that the switch auto-assigns IP 192.168.0.1 if it can't reach a DHCP Server.*
- On `802.1Q VLAN Configuration`, input `1` for the VLAN ID, and mark ALL ports as **Tagged**. Click on Add/Modify.
- Now input `2` for VLAN ID, and mark all ports you wish as **Untagged**. (Remember to add the tagged/untagged trunk also). Click on Add/Modify.

With this setup, I was able to confirm that no traffic from VLAN1/untagged escapes to another port.

As the other answer also said, it's better to just leave VLAN 1 for management purposes and you can avoid all this problems altogether.